BPMN to Petri nets converter or any other tool for verification
My goal is to transfer a BPMN model to any workflow tool that will allow me to verify it. I learned about Petri nets, so I want to be able to transform an XML file I obtained after creating a BPMN model into a Petri net. Is there a tool for doing this?
I kept finding some scientific papers from The Netherlands but they are decades old and the websites for source code do not work.
I'd appreciate any help.
EDIT:
There is a verification tool like BehaVerify for behaviour trees. I'd like a similar tool for my BPMN, but from what I see it doesn't exist. Therefore, I need to convert it into Petri nets or similar to have it verified.

What do you mean by "verification"?  BPMN is XML format and contains a schema.  You can verify by simply doing a schema check.  Petri nets is a graphic output and not sure why you need the graphics.  There are plenty of tools that will verify an XML using the schema.

All BehaVerify does is create a python tree for xml.  Tree structures for XML can be done in many programming languages .  I prefer Powershell.  Are you trying to verify or simply parse the XML file?

I want to verify using some sort to temporal logic specification, similar to what can be done to behaviour trees.

The verification is done using the schema.  Schema are best used when generating the XML file by the people who create the file.  You can create classes for the XML file by taking the schema(s) and creating classes using the XSD.exe tool.  Do you have the schemas?

Just to clarify: the XSD tools "used to validate whether the structure and content of an XML document meet a set of defined criteria. If an XML document adheres to its corresponding XSD, it is considered valid."
Does it use a

XML must meet XML specification which defines the structure of all XML files.  The schema is used to validate the contents of the XML which is the names of the tags, requires attributes, and range/types of the values (of innertext and attributes).

I need a tool in the end that could do do symbolic model checking like nuXmv. XSD doesn't seem to do it?

You are looking for a tool that does language parsing like YACC on the values which is an app analysis of the contents of the XML.

Found a GitHub repo that does exactly what I want.
Their paper:
PM4Py: A process mining library for Python
